# File Format for an Animation

Tags: animation, file-format

What is the best file format for a short animation? I would like to make a folder with a bunch of animations which are different camera angles of the same Blender File. Is this even possible?

Comment: Greatly depends on what you're going to use it for. Is quality the most important part to you, or should the files be small to be a part of a video game? Please specify your question more. It's like asking "What's the best camera to take pictures with?"

Comment: There is no **best** format. It all depends on your goal. If you are rendering from blender you'll get more flexibility if you render as a image sequence and encode later.

Comment: I'm just trying to show the differences between how the particles are affected by the force field

Comment: I figured the best way to do so would be through having one animation showing everything, and then little ones focusing on just the individual fields (since I have 9 in total)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is very broad and has no definite answer.

With that being said, I'll write my answer as H.264. Why?

Among others, it's one of the most universal. High compression combined with high quality, especially compared to the compression ratio. I personally use it for most of my video renderings.

It's also broadly supported, and will run on all major platforms; Windows, Mac, browsers, iPhone/iPad, Android devices, Windows devices, etc.

If you decide, you can easily convert the video clip to MP4 at a later time if you so desire.

It's also one of the industry standards along with MP4, WAV, OGG and more.

So again, this is more of a personal answer on a broad question.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes! Thank you, I have to wait to post my next question which is going to be the next step on my project. I can comment here once its up. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: You're welcome. But please, specify your question(s) to keep them from being too broad. Broad questions will get a lot of speculation and negativity. To receive the best help for your specific situation, specific details are needed.

Comment: Sorry! I'm pretty new to blender so its a bit tough to be specific. Once I do get the files rendered in that format can I save them in once big file? Like on google drive or just a file folder. I just want the animations not the whole file

Comment: Rendering as an image sequence first will allow you to then play with different compression codecs and bitrates until you find the one that works for you.

Comment: As cegaton mentions, rendering in image sequences will allow you more freedom. But if you're new I still recommend H.264 for its simplicity. And yes, you can combine them into one file or add them in a single folder, just like any other video format.

Comment: I just posted another question. Please let me know if you need more information, which I'm sure you might